# Ergodicity regarding links in networks

Tags: ergodic-theory, network

I am reading this article where it explains an ergodic assumption regarding links but I do not quite understand what the autor means.

> The “ergodic assumption” of random link switching is of course
> extremely restrictive, and unlikely to be satisfied by most real
> systems; thus a snapshot of a temporal information that includes all
> edges over a fixed time scale can lose a large amount of information:
> a possible measure of this loss can be found in a comparison of paths
> in a snapshot and time-respecting paths in the temporal network. In a
> snapshot, because of the loss of temporal information, we may see
> paths that are temporally impossible routes of contagion flow, giving
> us a false idea of the potential infection flow between pairs of
> nodes. The fraction of snapshot paths that are not time-respecting
> (and therefore could not transmit infection from the starting to
> ending nodes) is a rough measure of how important it is to use a
> temporal network rather than a static snapshot when determining
> potential infection flow between nodes.
>
> For example, in the cattle trading network in Great Britain, only
> about half of the paths of two contacts are time-respecting for
> timeframes over a week, with a substantially smaller fraction being
> time-respecting for longer paths. The fraction of paths that are
> temporally possible decreases slightly as longer timeframes are used
> for the snapshot. When measuring properties of individual nodes,
> distance in a snapshot therefore may be a poor proxy for disease flow
> by animal trade between two farms in the Great Britain cattle trading
> network, and therefore in this case the loss of the temporal
> information in the static approximation could result in substantially
> incorrect predictions of disease spread, though it may still give
> qualitatively useful insight (Kao et al., 2006).

as I understand ergodicity is that an activity is ergodic if the outcome is the same for many people performing it once and one person performing it many times. but I do not quite understand what the author means here